# How to use very small size button (24dp) android

Tags: android, material-design, android-button

Iam designing a food ordering page, so i need to use small button to add the food on cart.The problem was when i giving 24dp width and height the button size reduces but i cant able to add the text("+" "-").

I have tried

> android:minWidth="0dp"
>   android:minHeight="0dp"
>   style="?android:attr/negativeButtonText"

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/incrementButtton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@color/ash"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fm_food_price_text_size" />
```

I want to know how to set button  24dp and show "+" text. as like below image.
In this image i used textView, so text is visibile. I want this by using button.

[image]

Comment: get an image of that size and use that instead

Comment: there is also something called `ImageButton`

Comment: i want ripple effect like material button

Comment: for effect add this in ImageButton `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: Now I am feeling hungry! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by using ImageButton instead of button.

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/incrementButtton"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_minus_symbol"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
             />
```

for ripple effect i used

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. This is much more efficient

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_dp_85"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_dp_35"
            android:id="@+id/quantityviewer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/productName"
            android:background="@drawable/quantity"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/productName">

        <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/increase"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/decrease"
        />
        <ImageView
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/quantityviewer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/decrease"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/quantity"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/quantityviewer"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/quantityviewer"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        />
        <ImageView
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/quantityviewer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/increase"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/quantityviewer"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/quantityviewer"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quantity"
        />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**quantitiy.xml**(shape of the layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_dp_5" />
    <stroke
            android:width="@dimen/_dp_1"
            android:color="@color/quantitystokecolor" />
</shape>
```